# React.js white space

Tags: reactjs, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm having this issue that I can't solve. It appeared a white space between my first and second components, and I just can't understand where it came from. Nothing shows in the inspector. Here it is:

[image]

I'll leave a pic of my Navbar and Home components source code, so you can have a better look. I found the issue in the Navbar, without this ISSUE part, it cleans the top:

```
 import React from "react";
    import { Nav, Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
    
    const NavBar = () => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Navbar sticky="top" color="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">LOGO</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#about">ABOUT</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#community">COMMUNITY</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#location">LOCATION</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#menu">OUR MENU</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#recipes">RECIPES</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#contact">CONTACT</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#login">LOGIN</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar>
//ISSUE
          <Nav className="middle-navbar">
            <Nav.Link href="#">One</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link href="#info" className="ml-auto">
              REQUEST INFO
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
//ISSUE
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default NavBar;
```

And the Home:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Container fluid id="home-container">
      <h1>THE BEST FOODIE</h1>
      <h1 id="foddie-title">EXPERIENCE</h1>
      <h6>NOW IN LONDON</h6>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

And SCSS:

```
@import "_mixins";

@font-face {
  font-family: "din";
  src: local("din"), url(../fonts/DIN.ttf) format("truetype");
}

* {
  font-family: "din", sans-serif;
}

//NAVBAR
.middle-navbar {
  position: relative;
  top: 50vh;
}

//HOME
#home-container {
  background: url("../img/bg-pic.png");
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 100em;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Any help would be excellent :)

Comment: It would be good if you could, post a link to working code on some online playground.

Comment: Showing either a working example or the compiled HTML would be very helpful, style issues are generally a pain to debug without seeing it in action.

Comment: You're right, I'll try to put it in a codesand box :)

Comment: Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/white-space-b8m8v - I've put Navbar to fixed=''top" and it worked a little bit, but still has this little white space :/

Comment: I've posted the issue at the top, but still can't understand why it does it and how to solve it.

Comment: Sandbox looks fine to me (once I fixed the typo in your `Home` component export). I don't see the extra whitespace there.

Comment: Yes, thank you :) I just found the issue too, the problem was in the <Nav/>, because it needs to be wrapped in a <Navbar/> and then styled. Thank you so much for your help :)